# Is there a way or a tool to automatically visit all pages of my site

Tags: php, caching, web-crawler

I want to automatically visit / crawl all the pages on my site in order to generate a cache file. Is there any way or tool to do this?

Comment: Normally, the user visiting the page the first time generates the cached content - what's wrong with that approach?

Comment: no problem with that but in my db there are 13 to 20 lakes of record,but when I open any product it takes more time, if any user come to my site and they feel site is slow then why he come again thats why I want to any tool that will visit all links at least once so cache file is automatically generated.

Answer (score 3):

Just use any robot that downloads your entire page:

https://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website

For example wget:

```
wget -r --no-parent http://site.com/songs/
```

Comment: hey I dont want to download any page or entire website. I want to load all my pages at once.

Comment: If you had the list of all urls to fetch, you could use `--spider' option to download only the header for each url.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wget`'s recursive option to do this. Change `example.com` to your domain:

```
wget --recursive --no-parent --domains=example.com --level=inf --delete-after
```

Answer (score 1):

do you use a CMS? do you have a list of your pages? you could write a simple PHP loop to load all pages using CURL or php fopen()

```
$pages_ar = array(
    "http://mydomain.com/page1.htm",
    "http://mydomain.com/page2.htm",
    "http://mydomain.com/page2.htm",
);

foreach($pages_ar as $page)
{
   fopen($page, "r");
}
```

basic but I hope you get the idea...

Comment: do you use a CMS?->no, do you have a list of your pages?->no. My page url are automatically created from database according to my  category and type of product .I can not list out my  all pages because there are lakhs of url generated.

Comment: if your pages are all in a a db then creating the list of urls should be easy time.... just set up a query to your DB to create the list of pages and run my suggested idea - job done. As all you are trying to do is hit each page to run your webscript to create the cache files, this is a simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

surfen's method is correct but if you want a php solution you can check Symfony 2-s BrowserKit component which can be used as a stand alone component.

https://github.com/symfony/BrowserKit