# Load all site in RAM with Varnish

Tags: wordpress, caching, varnish, ram

I have a WordPress site on a Debian server with apache2 and Varnish. Can I use a script or program to load all the pages of my site automatically in RAM, so as to have them served much quicker? The usual setup implies that when a page is visited for the first time it is served by apache, and only afterwards is served by Varnish from cache. This means that many pages load quite slowly. I would like to have them all loaded in Varnish cache by a script and when they expire have them loaded again; of course all pages with the usual exception of 'my-account','wp-login','cart', etc., which I've already excluded in Varnish configuration. I think I have enough free RAM to load all the pages.

Comment: You can.

I guess it won't be difficult to make a script in python or ruby to "visit" your pages. Or even bash with wget.

Then you can use crontab to run that script every N minutes.

Comment: How do you write a script to visit all the pages of a website? I haven't found anything useful searching for an answer. And I don't think 'wget' or 'curl' can do it as they can be applied only to specific individual pages that you have to mention yourself, whereas I would want a script or program that automatically visits all the pages of a website.

Comment: In a quick search I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9944945/1423901